# How to use templates with Slim?

Tags: php, templates, twig, slim

http://www.slimframework.com/docs/tutorial/first-app.html shows using "plain old PHP" (Composer package is `php-view` and class is `PhpRenderer`) for templates as follows:

```
<?php
// Create app
$app = new \Slim\App();

// Get container
$container = $app->getContainer();

$container['view'] = new \Slim\Views\PhpRenderer("../templates/");

$app->get('/tickets', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    $this->logger->addInfo("Ticket list");
    $mapper = new TicketMapper($this->db);
    $tickets = $mapper->getTickets();

    $response = $this->view->render($response, "tickets.phtml", ["tickets" => $tickets]);
    return $response;
});

// Run app
$app->run();
```

The above page states using Twig for templates is basically the same, but http://www.slimframework.com/docs/features/templates.html shows a very different approach.  Which is the correct way to use templates, and specifically how should I use Twig for templates?

```
<?php
// Create app
$app = new \Slim\App();

// Get container
$container = $app->getContainer();

// Register component on container
$container['view'] = function ($container) {
    $view = new \Slim\Views\Twig('path/to/templates', [
        'cache' => 'path/to/cache'
    ]);
    $view->addExtension(new \Slim\Views\TwigExtension(
        $container['router'],
        $container['request']->getUri()
    ));

    return $view;
};

// Render Twig template in route
$app->get('/hello/{name}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    return $this->view->render($response, 'profile.html', [
        'name' => $args['name']
    ]);
})->setName('profile');

// Run app
$app->run();
```

Comment: I would like to suggest using the [Slim Skeleton](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Skeleton) application. Twig templating is already integrated.

Comment: @Peter  Slim Skeleton doesn't use Twig.  There approach, however, is more like the Twig example in that it uses an anonymous function unlike the "First Application Walkthrough".

Comment: Your second code block is the right way to use Twig in Slim 3. Is it what you want to know?